# How can i plot 2 string variables Pol vs Ch

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-2.7, valueerror

I want to plot Ch and Pol strings but i can't convert them into a plotable variables

```
Ch = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22'
Pol = '9 9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 9 10 10 10 10 10 10'
plt.plot(Ch,Pol)
```

When i run it the result is:

> ValueError: Unrecognized character 9 in format string

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must split the strings into individual number-like substrings with `split()` and then convert each substring into a number (int or float):

```
plt.plot(
    list(map(float, Ch.split())),
    list(map(float, Pol.split())))
```